# LInq on a complex Object Converted from Json

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a class created from a json response from a web service. I need to filter the row collection where the V[1] has a value of 12. Could I get some help with the proper linq to object to filter this collection? I'm lost on this object. I reduced it to a `List<Row>` but this one has me baffled.

[json and class code](https://app.quicktype.io?share=J7Ggu7f8akOCgEmPKiiU)

Image of the structure of the json object

[image]

Comment: The naming in this is atrocious, and hard to follow

Comment: in the json object? I totally agree

Comment: Additionally when you say `I need to filter the row collection` what do you exactly mean. return just the rows, or return the entire set, with only `rows` that contain `v[1] = 12` ?

Comment: The goal after retrieving the entire collection from the web service is to get a rows collection that only contain rows that have a 12 in the V\[1] position. Then I need to call additional service calls using another value from those rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var filterdRows = Data.Rows.Where(x => x.C[1].V.Integer == 12);
```

`x` is the `Row` object.
`x.C[1]` is the second `C` in the `Row`. I think, `C` is a column of a row.
`x.C[1].V.Integer` is the value of second column, if it contains integer value.

The result will be an enumerable of `Row`s.

Comment: This is potentially going to break all over the shop

Comment: so close Mark var filterdRows = lc.Data.Rows.Where(x => x.C[1].V?.Integer == 12); But I can tell you now I wouldn't have figured this out. That did gve me 1 row

Comment: @michael I completely agree. Not much I can do though, I don't control the service

Comment: @Tim Dont forget the `x.C.Count >= 2` otherwise this will throw sooner or later

Comment: @MichaelRandall ok that makes sence